# Problem with answer to a harder question

Tags: discussion, answers, wrong-answers

There is a [particular question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788924/how-to-prepare-data-for-display-on-a-silverlight-chart-using-wcf-ria-services-e) which I found interesting and I don't think it is poorly written, but the accepted answer I find goes against everything that Stack Overflow stands for (and it has an upvote. WTF?).

I raised it for moderator attention, although I'm not sure what the outcome could possibly be. I just wanted to know what others thought of this particular case.

Comment: Yeah, it feels strange flagging an answer posted by the asker for mod attention, but in cases like this, it's definitely merited. I've done this a couple of times myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I agree; that isn't an answer to the question, and isn't helpful to anyone *including* the OP. Fortunately that answer (ahem) no longer exists.

I can't speak for the downvote, other than it isn't part of a group of dodgy / inappropriate votes or anything like that - just an odd vote. Sometimes it happens.

Comment: to quote mr burns...Excellent!